# How do I switch between multiple users in KitKat via Lockscreen?

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens, multi-user

I am using CynogenMod CM11 R22 on the Xiaomi Redmi 1S phone.  I enabled multiple users using adb:

```
cd /system
pm get-max-users
setprop fw.max_users 3
echo "" >> build.prop
echo "#" >> build.prop
echo "# ADDING USER TO SETTINGS" >> build.prop
echo "#" >> build.prop
echo fw.max_users=3 >> build.prop
echo "" >> build.prop
echo "" >> build.prop
echo "" >> build.prop
echo "" >> build.prop
```

I can toggle between users using the Power menu,  but I want to show them on the Lock screen. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple user support was designed for tablets only in 4.4 KitKat, and therefore the user picker only appears in landscape mode.  On CM11 for phones you will need to enable lockscreen rotation by adding a line `lockscreen.rot_override=true` to your build.prop file in the same manner as you did to enable multiple users:

```
echo "lockscreen.rot_override=true" >> build.prop
```

Reboot, rotate the phone to landscape mode, and you should see the user picker on the lockscreen.