# Cannot switch between users on Android 4.4 (CM11)

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, multi-user

I have enabled multi-user support on a phone running CyanogenMod 11 (KitKat) by adding the following to `/system/build.prop`:

```
fw.show_multiuserui=1
fw.max_users=4
```

and I was able to create a new user after that.

However, I still can't switch between users because there is nothing on my lock screen that would allow me to do this (no user switcher or whatever it's called), same in Power menu. I rebooted the phone multiple times.

I can only switch between users via adb or a terminal app using `am switch-user <user-id>`, and only as root (so not from non-owner user).

After reading this question:

[How do I switch between multiple users in KitKat via Lockscreen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102134/how-do-i-switch-between-multiple-users-in-kitkat-via-lockscreen?newreg=cab028a5a71e467989ee5b7e442a88f6)

I additionally added `lockscreen.rot_override=true` to build.prop in order to enable rotating into landscape mode for lock screen but it didn't work.

How do I enable the GUI for switching between users?

Comment: what happens while  tapping on avatar on notification panel

Comment: @RahulGopi Not much, it just goes to lock screen

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I forgot to disable rotation the lock in display settings. This was preventing lock screen from rotating.

(Still nothing in Power menu though.)